# In Python3, Why list object is an iterable but not iterator directly?

Tags: python, list, iterator, iterable

I do know object implemented **iter**() is a iterable, and **next** is a iterator.
but i'm confused why list object in python3 doesn't implement **next** directly.

```
l = list((1,2,3))
l_iterator = l.__iter__()
l_iterator.__next__() 
...
```

is there some ingenious mechanism i missed?

Comment: An iterator needs to maintain state. It is not desirable that the list maintains this state. You would have no way to reset the iteration once you already iterated the list.

Comment: @trincot Well, [PHP does it that way](https://www.php.net/next), but yes, it can have surprising behaviour and lead to subtle bugs.

Comment: A bad decision in the PHP language, which then has to offer `reset($array)`. Ugly.

Comment: Please don't use PHP as an example for language design.

Comment: @Keith It's a great example for *bad* language design…!

Comment: Containers are generally not supposed to be iterators, that's the whole point - separation of concerns. One example of an advantage is if you want to create multiple separate iterators over the same container.

Answer (score -1):

You only need to use the double underscores when defining iterator and next methods for a custom class. I think in this case, here is what you are looking to do:

```
l = list((1,2,3))
l_iterator = iter(l)
next(l_iterator)
```

Comment: The Asker knows this. They are asking about a language design decision.